# Flask Compare strings

Tags: python, flask

If I upload a file to my flask script and I don't like it, I set filename to "None" so it shows a default image. Then, in my Flask template, I want to test to see if filename is "None"; if so, show the default. Else, show the file. Here is my template code, which does not work:

```html
<!doctype html>
<title>Hello from Flask</title>
{% if {{filename}} is "None" %}:
  <h1>some text<img src="{{filename}}"> more text!</h1>
{% else %}
  <h1>Impossible file: here is tha default so<img src="MB.png"> boi</h1>
{% endif %}
```

I think the problem lies in the string compare. I cannot figure out how to properly compare strings, I think.

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What about this?

```
{% if filename == "None" %}
```

You don't need double brackets inside `{% %}`

Ex: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/templates/builtins/#operator

Comment: django docs for a flask question?

Answer (score 3):

Set `filename` to `None` (or the empty string if you must use a string for some reason), not the string `"None"`. Test the variable or use `is not none`.

```
{% if filename %}
```

```
{% if filename is not none %}
```